# Veryfy some properties of a given Borel set.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, borel-sets

> for a given $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$
>   $$A_{n,\epsilon}=\bigcup_{\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}}(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{\epsilon}{q^n},\frac{p}{q}+\frac{\epsilon}{q^n}),
> A_n=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}A_{n,\epsilon}$$

1.$\bigcap_{n}A_{n}\ne\mathbb{Q}$.

2.$\bigcap_{n}A_{n}$ is an uncountable set.

3.$\bigcap_{n}A_{n}-\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

I think it's enough to consider $\widetilde{A}_{n,\epsilon}=A_{n,\epsilon}\bigcap[0,1],\widetilde{A}_{n}=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\widetilde{A}_{n,\epsilon}$ satisfying those properites.

As we change the position of $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$, we get A exactly the $\mathbb{Q}$, so
I'm interested in this one.

Comment: Hint: [Liouville numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) are in $\bigcap_n A_n$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks a lot!I didn't know they even have a name.